# How to manage MultiIndex when using pandas.to_latex()?

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I have a a list of somehow big tables (~3000rows each) from which I need to publish to latex some aggregated results, but I can't make the table "look" as I need.

*Note: I have many tables to put into LaTeX, so I'd prefer a python solution instead of a LaTeX one.*

I already explored 2 options, both without success.
On the 1st option, my code is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_pickle("org_df.pkl")
df_all_print = df.groupby(['dataset', 'Model']).mean()
#df_all_print.reset_index(inplace=True)
latex = df_all_print.to_latex(
    # index=False,
    escape=False, sparsify=True, multirow=True, multicolumn=True, position='H'
)
with open(tbl_path / f'{filename}.tex', 'w') as table:
    table.write(latex)
```

But the output after rendering in LaTeX is (I don't want the 2 lines in the header, I want 'dataset','Model','F-1+ and 'F-2' in the same line):

[image]

In the 2nd option, I try to correct this issue by resetting the index:

```
df = pd.read_pickle("org_df.pkl")
df_all_print = df.groupby(['dataset', 'Model']).mean()
df_all_print.reset_index(inplace=True)
latex = df_all_print.to_latex(
    index=False,
    escape=False, sparsify=True, multirow=True, multicolumn=True, position='H'
)
with open(tbl_path / f'{filename}.tex', 'w') as table:
    table.write(latex)
```

but after rendering it looks like this:

[image]

which has the header correct, but has a different set of problems (no multiline ability, ie, I would like only one occurrence of each dataset 'G','H','S','T' as in the above; and also I lost the `\midrow` below the group of datasets).

The questions are:

- Is there any way I can define after which specific rows I want a `\midrow`?
- How can I obtain the intended solution?

[image]

For reproducibility, here goes a reduced version of the `org_df` dict:

```
this_dict={'Model': {0: 'Baseline', 1: 'Baseline', 2: 'Baseline', 3: 'Baseline', 4: 'Baseline', 5: 'Baseline', 6: 'Baseline', 7: 'Baseline', 8: 'Baseline', 9: 'Baseline', 10: 'Baseline', 11: 'Baseline', 12: 'Baseline', 13: 'Baseline', 14: 'Baseline', 15: 'Baseline', 16: 'Baseline', 17: 'Baseline', 18: 'Baseline', 19: 'Baseline', 20: 'Baseline', 21: 'Baseline', 22: 'Baseline', 23: 'Baseline', 24: 'Version2', 25: 'Version2', 26: 'Version2', 27: 'Version2', 28: 'Version2', 29: 'Version2', 30: 'Version2', 31: 'Version2', 32: 'Version2', 33: 'Version2', 34: 'Version2', 35: 'Version2', 36: 'Version2', 37: 'Version2', 38: 'Version2', 39: 'Version2', 40: 'Version2', 41: 'Version2', 42: 'Version2', 43: 'Version2', 44: 'Version2', 45: 'Version2', 46: 'Version2', 47: 'Version2'}, 'dataset': {0: 'H', 1: 'H', 2: 'H', 3: 'H', 4: 'H', 5: 'H', 6: 'S', 7: 'S', 8: 'S', 9: 'S', 10: 'S', 11: 'S', 12: 'G', 13: 'G', 14: 'G', 15: 'G', 16: 'G', 17: 'G', 18: 'T', 19: 'T', 20: 'T', 21: 'T', 22: 'T', 23: 'T', 24: 'H', 25: 'H', 26: 'H', 27: 'H', 28: 'H', 29: 'H', 30: 'S', 31: 'S', 32: 'S', 33: 'S', 34: 'S', 35: 'S', 36: 'G', 37: 'G', 38: 'G', 39: 'G', 40: 'G', 41: 'G', 42: 'T', 43: 'T', 44: 'T', 45: 'T', 46: 'T', 47: 'T'}, 'F-1': {0: 1.0, 1: 0.2983425414364641, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.4705882352941177, 4: 0.9245283018867924, 5: 0.9836065573770492, 6: 0.4927536231884056, 7: 0.3589743589743589, 8: 0.3689320388349514, 9: 0.4375, 10: 0.2758620689655172, 11: 0.4722222222222222, 12: 0.9761904761904762, 13: 1.0, 14: 0.9902912621359222, 15: 1.0, 16: 0.9887640449438202, 17: 0.8695652173913043, 18: 0.9690721649484536, 19: 0.663013698630137, 20: 0.9987325728770596, 21: 0.9991015274034142, 22: 1.0, 23: 0.654320987654321, 24: 1.0, 25: 0.3296703296703296, 26: 1.0, 27: 0.5263157894736842, 28: 0.9622641509433962, 29: 0.9836065573770492, 30: 0.5217391304347826, 31: 0.3589743589743589, 32: 0.4901960784313725, 33: 0.5161290322580646, 34: 0.3103448275862069, 35: 0.5217391304347826, 36: 0.9761904761904762, 37: 1.0, 38: 0.9902912621359222, 39: 1.0, 40: 0.9887640449438202, 41: 0.8695652173913043, 42: 0.9690721649484536, 43: 0.9877800407331976, 44: 0.9962073324905184, 45: 0.9991015274034142, 46: 1.0, 47: 0.979214780600462}, 'F-2': {0: 1.0, 1: 0.2967032967032967, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.3711340206185567, 4: 0.9245283018867924, 5: 0.9782608695652174, 6: 0.3695652173913043, 7: 0.3191489361702128, 8: 0.2714285714285714, 9: 0.3888888888888889, 10: 0.2105263157894736, 11: 0.3617021276595745, 12: 0.9761904761904762, 13: 1.0, 14: 0.9807692307692308, 15: 1.0, 16: 0.9777777777777776, 17: 0.8695652173913043, 18: 0.9657534246575342, 19: 0.4969199178644763, 20: 0.9974683544303796, 21: 0.9982046678635548, 22: 1.0, 23: 0.4907407407407407, 24: 1.0, 25: 0.3260869565217391, 26: 1.0, 27: 0.4123711340206185, 28: 0.9433962264150944, 29: 0.9782608695652174, 30: 0.391304347826087, 31: 0.3191489361702128, 32: 0.3623188405797101, 33: 0.4705882352941176, 34: 0.2368421052631578, 35: 0.4090909090909091, 36: 0.9761904761904762, 37: 1.0, 38: 0.9807692307692308, 39: 1.0, 40: 0.9777777777777776, 41: 0.8695652173913043, 42: 0.9657534246575342, 43: 0.9758551307847082, 44: 0.9924433249370276, 45: 0.9982046678635548, 46: 1.0, 47: 0.976958525345622}}
```

To use it, just replace my 1st line of code by `df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(this_dict)`

Comment: I don't think your dict for reproduceability is valid. I get a dataframe with only one column called `df_csv` and it's full of weird CSV strings. You know, you can do `print(df.to_dict())`

Comment: thanks for the notice, I already corrected it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I had to implement some code to change the latex table afterwards.